# MSIL virtual addresses

Tags: .net, vb.net, cil

Please have a look at the MSIL code below:

```
IL_00:  ldstr      "Hello World"
IL_05:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_10:  ret
```

What is meant by IL_00, IL_05 and IL_10? I read Operating System concepts at university so I understood at the time how the Windows operating system allocates virtual memory to a process.  I also don't understand why in the case of the above; the addresses increment by 5.

The managed code was generated from a VB.NET application.

I have spent some time Googling this and I have read a few articles on MSDN.  I am still not clear and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: If you have a new, mostly unrelated, question, *ask a new question*, don't edit your old one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are just fake "addresses" generated by your IL disassembler.  The LDSTR opcode requires one byte for the opcode, 0x72, and 4 bytes for the operand.  Which is a token value that selects the string from the metadata table that stores string literals.  So the next IL opcode starts at offset 5.  Same recipe there, CALL requires one byte for the opcode, 0x28, and 4 bytes for the operand, the method token.  So the next IL opcode starts at offset 10.  RET requires 1 byte, 0x2A and has no operand.  Total IL code size is 11 bytes.

Your disassembler generates these "addresses" to show you the target of a branch instruction.  You don't have one, try disassembling code that uses an if() statement to see that.  They are otherwise immaterial since the jitter translates this code to machine code which looks very different.

Comment: Are they not just labels like other ASM-looking languages?

Comment: Well, kind of.  If you program in IL then you'd actually use a symbolic label and don't put a label on every IL instruction.  Just the ones that matter, the target of branch opcodes.  This is just extra data generated by the disassembler, same thing you see when you look at disassembled machine code.

Comment: In the answer you reference a hexadecimal number (0x72), which is decimal 114.  I don't understand what this refers to? +1 for a clear answer.

Comment: Please ignore the comment above.  I realise that each opcode has a binary code i.e. 0x72 in the case of LDSTR.

Comment: It is not an address, simply a value that identifies the opcode.  Inside the assembly the IL is just raw bytes.  The disassembler converted 0x72 to "LDSTR".  It also knows that LDSTR has an operand, 4 bytes in the IL.  And did you the favor of translating that token value to the actual string "Hello world".  It did so by looking up the string in the metadata table of the assembly.  So beware that what you see from the disassembler is heavily doctored from the original IL bytes.

Comment: Yes, you can see the machine code generated by the jitter.  Start debugging and use Debug + Windows + Disassembly

Comment: Thanks, but there is no option for Dissassembly in Debug\Windows.  There are options for Immediate, Local, breakpoints etc.  I tried following your advice in another post i.e. enabling address level debugging in Debugging options.  Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: As I noted in the previous comment, you do need to start debugging to get this option.  You can only look at machine code when the jitter has translated the IL.  Which it will only do when it needs to, actually running the program is required.  Press F11.

Comment: @Hans Passant, this is what I was doing. I have edited the question. Could you take a look at the edit? Thanks again.

Comment: This just doesn't have anything to do with the original question anymore.  You'll need to start a new question.

Comment: I have posted the further question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548073/visual-studio-2008-disassembly-option-not-appearing.  I thought I would let you know in case you are able/willing to help further.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the great insight @Hans. Your information here really cleared up some things for me.